# Adding custom measure to multiple portfolios

Tags: sonarqube

I have to add custom measure to our portfolios as shown in the attached image. Since we have good number of portfolios I am trying automate this with scripts. I investigated api details in developer tools of my browser for manual addition of this metric but that was not of much help to me.

Is there any api for this task, api that can help me to add custom measure to portfolios?

[image]